# Search and Compare Columns to Create New Columns (Teradata SQL)

Tags: sql, row, teradata, operations

I have a dataset with Sale event history, and i need to create a column to show if the sale is still active.  My dataset looks like this:

```
item | original_price | sale1 | sale2 | sale3 | current_price
-----|----------------|-------|-------|-------|--------------
1    | 3.00           | 2.75  | ?     | ?     | 2.75
2    | 4.00           | ?     | 3.50  | ?     | 4.00
3    | 10.00          | 7.50  | ?     | 8.50  | 8.50
```

in the case of `item 1`, the new field should say **active** since the item is still at the `sale1` price.  `Item 2` should say **nonactive**, because the price is no longer at a sale price.
`Item 3` was on sale, then was not, and is now on sale again **active**.
So, the SQL needs to pull in all of these fields, and create a new column by comparing `current_price` to the most recent salex variable.

I need to implement this into a current SQL process, but do not know how to do this syntactically.  thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to match your defintion:

```
case
   when coalesce(sale3, sale2, sale1) = current_price then 'active'
   else 'nonactive'
end
```

Comment: Thank you @dnoeth. This works perfectly.  I had an issue implementing, but it was due to how i was coding the missing values ('' vs NULL).